# How to Drag-and-Move Files between drives on Windows 7 by Default?

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop

Whenever I drag files from my desktop to a secondary drive on my Windows 7 PC it copies by default.  I know I can shift+drag it over but what I'd like to do is make the default move instead of copy.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Apparently [it's the same for Mac OS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/move-elements-between-folders-not-copy/e0ff4e3c-9961-4ff0-b8d7-c582bbfac920).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure there's a way to override the default behavior within windows. You can always right-click drag and upon releasing right click, select move. Takes an extra second and at least you don't have to hold SHIFT down..